# Assets missing in Android .apk file

Tags: android, c++, native

I'm using the **native** android sample in libfont: https://github.com/julienr/libfont to make an Android C++ application that can display text.

The build tool is Visual Studio https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/android-and-ios-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/.

The C/C++ code is located in the jni subdirectory, the font file LiberationSans-Bold.ttf is located in assets subdirectory in the libfont sample.

The app compiles and builds ok but the font file is not included in the final .apk

```
//
// To test if the assets are in the assets directory
//
bool _testFont()
{
    AAssetManager* manager = getApp()->activity->assetManager;

    AAssetDir* assetDir = AAssetManager_openDir(manager, "");   // Open root assets dir, assetDir is not NULL
    const char* fileName = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(assetDir); // Get first filename there -> fileName is NULL
}
//
// Original code 
//
bool _loadFont()
{
    LOGI("Loading font");

    AAssetManager* manager = getApp()->activity->assetManager;
    AAsset* fontFile = AAssetManager_open(manager, "LiberationSans-Bold.ttf", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
    //
    // Here fontfile is always NULL
    //
    if (!fontFile) 
    {
        LOGE("Error loading font file");
        return false;
    }
    const void* fontData = AAsset_getBuffer(fontFile);
    off_t fontLen = AAsset_getLength(fontFile);
    font = fontlib::FTLib::getInstance()->loadMemoryFont((const char*)fontData, fontLen, 30);
    AAsset_close(fontFile);
    if (!font)
    {
        LOGE("Error loading font");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**So my question is:**
***What mechanism in the building process makes the linker bring along the file(s) in the assets directory?***

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to include the font file. Using custom_rules.xml seems to be the proper way to accomplish this but I didn't have any luck with that approach. Instead I put the assets folder in the Packaging project folder and added three lines to the file ***(Solution_name).Packaging.androidproj***

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="assets\LiberationSans-Bold.ttf" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then the font file content was included in the .apk and could be accessed with Asset Manager as described in my previous post.